# Error in Arduino Library file

Tags: c++, library

I am working on a project which includes Arduino and a fingerprint scanner. It is completely based on embedded system. But then, I have downloaded a library for the fingerprint scanner. When I run the program I get an error which maps to the cpp file of the library file. See below to see the error and the library file.

**Error**

> FPS_GT511C3\FPS_GT511C3.c.cpp.o: In function
>   Command_Packet::GetPacketBytes()':
>   C:\Users\Dipti\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FPS_GT511C3/FPS_GT511C3.c.cpp:17:
>   undefined reference tooperator new[](unsigned int)'
>   FPS_GT511C3\FPS_GT511C3.c.cpp.o: In function
>   FPS_GT511C3::GetResponse()':
>   C:\Users\Dipti\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FPS_GT511C3/FPS_GT511C3.c.cpp:735:
>   undefined reference tooperator new[](unsigned int)' collect2.exe:
>   error: ld returned 1 exit status

Library File (CPP)

> byte* packetbytes= new byte[12];
>
> byte* resp = new byte[12];

Comment: Not sure if having your files having an extension of `.c.cpp` would confuse things, it they're C++ it'd be more conventional if they were just `.cpp`.

Comment: No. That doesn't make any difference because it is just the file name with .cpp extension.

Comment: Do you have a `typedef` for `byte` somewhere in scope at that location? `byte` is not a fundamental type and is usually typedef'ed to char or unsigned char.

Comment: What version of the IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using Arduino IDE 1.6.5. But then, I tried it with different version of IDE like 1.0.5, 1.0.6. It still shows the same problem. @Majenko

Comment: Try 1) removing the library and writing in the main sketch `byte *test = new byte[12];`. If this works the library has problems. Then 2) Try looking in the library. Probably something is redefining `new`

Comment: @frarugi87 Okay. I removed the library from the sketch and wrote the test code. It showed the same error. So I guess there is nothing wrong with the library. What next?

Comment: Then you have two ways to proceed: start with a working example (just a plain file with empty setup and loop, for instance) and gradually add every feature you need, until you find the broken one, or start removing features from your own one until it works. This way you'll be able to find the code that issues the problem

Comment: But there is no much feature in it. It is just the simple example code which comes with the library and the fingerprint scanner. https://github.com/sparkfun/Fingerprint_Scanner-TTL  Please go through this link and maybe download this library and try it out. @frarugi87

Comment: As I told you, my usual debug workflow is adding one feature at a time, then compile and see if it works. You said that removing the library leaves the error, so try starting from scratch and then adding code slowly. At present I can't download it.. Probably this evening I'll be able to do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of the problem is that the code is being compiled as C and not C++.

The error says 'new[]' is undefined at the link stage.  This is because the linker is not pulling in the C++ standard libraries.  The built-in function new[] it doesn't exist in C.

The filename FPS_GT511C3.c.cpp is the elephant in the room.  You could consider renaming it (and others) to FPS_GT511C3.cpp.  Although the plain Arduino IDE does not really have a problem with building them.

Another option might be to modify the new[] (and delete[]) for C's malloc() and free().  However this is only appropriate for the allocation of simple types (byte, int, etc).  If the code also allocates objects, it's not possible to simply swap these functions out since C++ (default) initialisation is be going on.